# Set Read and Publish Permissions for same session

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, permissions

Hey I'm trying to use two different type of permissions.

I know that I cant set the permission to the LoginButton authButton  together like this:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("friends_games_activity"));
authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

and I need to call

```
authButton.clearPermissions();
```

between them

But that meen If the user for example read data
and now need to send for example score by clicking "SEND SCORE" button
He need to press the login button again

Is there a way to change the Session permission Without reconnecting and pressing loggin button?

How can I add the 2 permissions (friends_games_activity and publish_actions) without problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Scrumptious sample app that ships with the SDK. In particular the SelectionFragment class. Inside there's a method called handleAnnounce, it shows the recommended way of requesting additional permissions.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/SelectionFragment.java#L206

Answer (score 0):

```
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setPublishPermissions("publish_actions");
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new 
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("friends_games_activity"));
    Session.getActiveSession().requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In its current state your answer might not be of any use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.